# Custom NSAttributedString attribute fails with error only in Xcode playground

Tags: xcode, swift, nsattributedstring, swift-playground

The following code works fine on iOS device and simulator, but fails in Xcode playground (run with iOS platform set in playground file inspector):

```
class ACertainStringAttribute: NSObject {}
NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Test", attributes: ["MyCustomAttribute" : ACertainStringAttribute()])
```

It builds and run perfectly on device, but in playground I get the following runtime error:

```
2015-11-15 11:49:08.808 Test[38055:1538435] -[__lldb_expr_154.ACertainStringAttribute encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd69c074d0
```

Why is there this difference?

Comment: Looks like your attribute doesn't conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: If that's true, it should error when running on the device or simulator, not just playground :-/

Comment: I guess not.  The playground must be doing something different; I don't know Swift well enough to tell you what though.

Comment: Are those two lines *the only code* both in the playground and the app?

Comment: Yes, only two lines in playground (excluding `import Foundation`), and tested in a new iOS Xcode project ran in simulator. Works in app, not on playground. Running on iOS 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Playground** tries to **render the string immediately after instantiation** (to preview it in the Result Sidebar). The rendering code must internally rely on attributes conforming to `NSCoding` – hence the immediate exception.

If you paste the same code **in the actual app**, however, it **doesn't automatically render** the string – it just creates an instance of `NSMutableAttributedString` – that's all.

Of course, if you try to set it on, let's say, `UILabel.attributedText`, app will crash with the same exception while rendering the string.

Comment: Ah that's it. I use custom attributes in my code and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Then I just realised I translate my custom attributes into standard attributes before display! So that's why it never crashes. Thanks!